# How to debug my word search code in C++?

Tags: c++

I need some help with my C++ word search code. I got it to work but not as what I intended.

When I run the code it scans my text file I inputted and only output one of the words in the text file that match the array in my code. When I add other words to the text file that is in the array it gives me a error.

And can someone please help me change it so it more in c++ code?

---

This is what I want to look like:

[image: This is what i want to look like]

And this is what I get:

[image: And this is what i got]

---

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <iomanip>


#define SIZE 30
using namespace std;



const char *Phish[SIZE] ={"Amazon","official","bank","security",          
"urgent","Alert","important","inform  ation", "ebay", "password", "credit", "verify",
"confirm", "account","bill", "immediately", "address", "telephone","SSN", "charity",
"check", "secure", "personal", "confidential",
"ATM", "warning","fraud","Citibank","IRS", "paypal"};

int point[SIZE] =      {2,2,1,1,1,1,2,2,3,3,3,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,3,2,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,1};                                                                               
int totalPoints[SIZE];

void outputResults();

int main(void)
{
    FILE *cPtr;
    char filename[100];
    char message[5000];
    char *temp[100];
    int i;
    int counter=0;
    int words=0;
    char *tokenPtr;

    cout << "Enter the name of the file to be read: \n";
    cin >> filename;

    if ( (cPtr = fopen(filename,"rb")) == NULL)
    {
        cout <<"File cannot be opened.\n";
    }
    else
    {
        fgets(message, 5000, cPtr);
        tokenPtr = strtok(message, " ");
        temp[0] = tokenPtr;
        while (tokenPtr!=NULL)
        {
            for(i=0; i< SIZE; i++)
            {
                if(strncmp(temp[0], Phish[i], strlen(Phish[i]))==0)
                {
                    totalPoints[i]++;
                    break;
                }

                tokenPtr =strtok(NULL, " ");
                temp[0] = tokenPtr;
                words++;

            }
            outputResults();

            cout << "\n";
            return 0;


        }
    }
}

void outputResults()
{
    int i;
    int count =0;
    int a;
    cout<<left<<setw(5) << "WORD "
        << setw(7)<<"# OF OCCURRENCE "
        << setw(15)<<"POINT TOTAL";

    for(i=0; i<SIZE; i++)
    {
        if(totalPoints[i] !=0)
        {
            cout<<"\n"<<left << setw(10)<< Phish[i]
                << setw(11)<< totalPoints[i]
                << setw(13)<< point[i]*totalPoints[i];
            count += point[i] * totalPoints[i];
        }
    }
    cout<< "\nPoint total for entire file: \n"<< count;
}
```

Comment: Hi, and welcome to Stack Overflow! You've definitely come to the right place to get high quality help with your coding issues. This high quality standard carries over to questions as well, and you will find the more effort you put into making your question, the more effort other users put into answers your question. You can refer to [this guide](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to make sure your questions are high quality! Always remember to include a description of what your code attempts to accomplish, any error messages, and examples of your input and output. And again, welcome!

Comment: `When I run the code it scans my text file i inputted and only output one of the words`  --  Look carefully at your `for` loop and what you do if you find the first word.  Or better yet, debug your code and see what the flow is when the first word is found.

Comment: @EricHtNguyen Did you step through your program using the debugger?  Or did you just run your program?  You need to step, one line at a time, through your program using the debugger, not just "run it".

Comment: o ok i probally just ran the program thanks

Comment: Also, this is a good time to rethink your program.  I know what you're *trying* to do, and that is to go through your whole list to see if the word is found.  But your list contains 30+ words.  So if the file contains 1,000 words, you will (at worse case) loop 30,000 times to search a file that contains 1,000 words.  That is highly inefficient, wouldn't you think so?  The better approach would be to store the words in a map-type structure (a `std::map`) get a word from the file, and search the map.

Answer (score 0):

First, your `for` loop is not written correctly.  What you want to do is take a word from the file, and search your phishing array for that word.  Right now, you are going through your `phishing` array without starting at the beginning of this array when you get a word.

Instead you should be taking a word, and then loop through the phishing array to see if the word exists.  If it's not found, then get the next word, check if it's in the array starting from the beginning, etc.

```
    fgets(message, 5000, cPtr);
    tokenPtr = strtok(message, " ");
    while (tokenPtr != NULL)
    {
        // start the search in the array
        for (i = 0; i < SIZE; i++)
        {
            if (strncmp(tokenPtr, Phish[i], strlen(Phish[i])) == 0)
            {
                totalPoints[i]++;
                break;
            }
        }

        // get the next word in the file
        tokenPtr = strtok(NULL, " ");
        words++;
     }
     outputResults();
```

You also don't need `temp[0]` at all in the program.  Just use `tokenPtr`.